# For each row of one table, count entries in another table pointing to each of those rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, group-by

Not sure the title explains the problem well; this is what I'm working with,

I have the following tables,

```
-- table = kms_doc_ref_currnt_v
DOC_ID    VARCHAR2(19)
TO_DOC_ID    VARCHAR2(19)
BRANCH_ID    NUMBER(8)
REF_TYP_CD    VARCHAR2(20)

-- table = kms_fil_nm_t
DOC_ID    VARCHAR2(19)    PRIMARY KEY    UNIQUE
```

For example, I can get a count of all `kms_doc_ref_currnt_v` records that have a `to_doc_id = 59678`, where 59678 is one value in `kms_fil_nm_t`, with this query,

```
select 'doc_id 59678 has ' || count(to_doc_id) as cnt from kms_doc_ref_currnt_v where branch_id=1 and ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA') and to_doc_id=59678;
```

`kms_doc_ref_currnt_v.to_doc_id` is a field that has one of the `kms_fil_nm_t.doc_id` values. `kms_doc_ref_currnt_v.doc_id` is also one of the values in `kms_fil_nm_t`.

The single query I'm looking for would loop over each `kms_fil_nm_t.doc_id` and count all the rows in `kms_doc_ref_currnt_v` that have a similar `to_doc_id`. Each row returned would look like the output of the query above. Here's example output,

```
doc_id 1 has 32
doc_id 2 has 314
doc_id 3 has 2718
doc_id 4 has 42
doc_id 5 has 128
doc_id 6 has 11235
.
.
.
```

Probably simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a join with two tables and add a `GROUP BY` clause as below:

```
    SELECT 'doc_id 59678 has ' || count(to_doc_id) as cnt 
    FROM kms_doc_ref_currnt_v kv, kms_fil_nm_t kt
    WHERE kt.doc_id= kv.to_doc_id 
          AND kv.branch_id=1 
          AND kv.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA') 
          AND kv.to_doc_id=59678
    GROUP BY kv.to_doc_id;
```

**EDIT:**

To get all records from `kms_doc_ref_currnt_v` irrespective of their reference availability in `kms_fil_nm_t` and `kv.to_doc_id=59678`, do like this:

```
    SELECT 'doc_id 59678 has ' || count(to_doc_id) as cnt 
    FROM kms_doc_ref_currnt_v kv 
         LEFT JOIN kms_fil_nm_t kt
         ON (kt.doc_id= kv.to_doc_id )
    WHERE  kv.branch_id=1 
          AND kv.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA') 
    GROUP BY kv.to_doc_id;
```

to replace the hardcoding `59678`, you may want to write:

```
    SELECT 'doc_id ' || kt.doc_id || ` has ' || count(to_doc_id) as cnt 
    FROM kms_doc_ref_currnt_v kv 
         LEFT JOIN kms_fil_nm_t kt
         ON (kt.doc_id= kv.to_doc_id )
    WHERE  kv.branch_id=1 
          AND kv.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA') 
    GROUP BY kv.to_doc_id, kt.doc_id;
```

Comment: This is close but not quite what I'm looking for. The `AND kv.to_doc_id=59678` part should be omitted. I want to know how many references each `doc_id` from `kms_fil_nm_t` has. Right now there's around 18k `doc_id`s. For each of those, I need to know how many records in `kms_doc_ref_currnt_v` have a `to_doc_id` matching the `doc_id`.

Almost works,

    SELECT ' has ' || count(kv.to_doc_id) as cnt FROM kms_doc_ref_currnt_v kv, kms_fil_nm_t kt WHERE kt.doc_id = kv.to_doc_id AND kv.branch_id=1 AND kv.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA') GROUP BY kv.to_doc_id ORDER BY cnt DESC;
    
Returns 6k rows.

Comment: @wsams: I am missing something here. Once you omit `AND kv.to_doc_id=59678`, still what is not working. Is it like records missing from kms_doc_ref_currnt_v if they don't have any reference? If yes, please refer my updated query in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting to see all of the records even if they have a count of 0, but suppose I don't really need that information.

Comment: Actually, I jumped the gun just a bit. In your edit, that query works, but I really need to know which `doc_id`s go with the count. But when I have more than one concatenation I get a `not a GROUP BY expression` error. So instead of `select 'doc_id 59678 has ' || count(to_doc_id)`, I need something like `select kt.doc_id || ' has ' || count(to_doc_id)`.

Comment: @wsams `You need to put all attributes being used in select in group by clause`. Please refer the updated answer.

Comment: Ah, I got it, `SELECT 'doc_id ' || kt.doc_id || ' has ' || count(kv.to_doc_id) as cnt 
    FROM kms_doc_ref_currnt_v kv 
         LEFT JOIN kms_fil_nm_t kt
         ON (kt.doc_id = kv.to_doc_id)
    WHERE  kv.branch_id = 1 
          AND kv.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA')
    GROUP BY kv.to_doc_id, kt.doc_id;` Thanks Yogendra.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#sthref2252) between the driving table that has all the `doc_id` values and the dependent table that may or may not have matching entries; and a [`group by`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6776) clause to define what your aggregate function (`count()`) is operating against. Something like:

```
select 'doc_id ' || t.doc_id || ' has ' || count(*)
from kms_fil_nm_t t
left join kms_doc_ref_currnt_v v
on v.to_doc_id = t.doc_id
and v.branch_id = 1
and v.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA')
group by t.doc_id;
```

This assumes you want to know when a `doc_id` isn't used, so you want entries like `doc_id 1234 has 0`. If you don't want to see those then you could use an inner join instead of an outer - essentially just remove the word `left` - but if that is the case then you don't really need to join at all, you could just do:

```
select 'doc_id ' || v.to_doc_id || ' has ' || count(*)
from kms_doc_ref_currnt_v v
where v.branch_id = 1
and v.ref_typ_cd in ('CONREF', 'KBA')
group by v.to_doc_id;
```

Unless there are `to_doc_id` values which are *not* in the other table, which would be included in the results of this query, but excluded if the tables were joined.

Comment: This works okay if I remove the first two parts of the concatenation. i.e. `'doc_id ' || t.doc_id ||` Otherwise I get a `not a GROUP BY expression` error.

Comment: @wsams - yes, that's what happens when I don't test code; I was grouping by the wrong field.