# R: How can I filter dates in one table, get the count, and return for each row of another table? Possible with dplyr and lubridate?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

First question, so please let me know if I'm missing anything in providing thorough information.

Background: I have two tables. One is a table of tech tickets and when they were opened and when they were solved (closed). I want to create a timeline which counts how many tickets were open on each day.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# load in data
tickets <- read.csv("tickets.csv",header=TRUE)


#packages
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tickets <- tbl_df(tickets)
tickets

## A tibble: 10 × 3
#ID Date.Time.Opened Date.Time.Closed
#<int>           <fctr>           <fctr>
#1      1    1/19/17 11:51    1/30/17 14:44
#2      2    1/22/16 12:27    1/30/17 13:36
#3      3    1/20/17 17:07     1/27/17 7:24
#4      4    1/20/17 18:23     1/27/17 7:24
#5      5     1/20/17 8:54    1/26/17 12:09
#6      6    1/24/17 18:54    1/26/17 12:09
#7      7    1/25/17 11:33    1/26/17 12:08
#8      8    1/23/17 11:22    1/25/17 16:31
#9      9    1/20/17 16:48    1/25/17 15:06
#10    10    1/9/17 8:57    1/25/17 13:46


#dates are currently factors; change to dates. 
tickets2 <- 
tickets %>%
mutate(Date.Time.Opened = mdy_hm(Date.Time.Opened)) %>%
mutate(Date.Time.Closed = mdy_hm(Date.Time.Closed))
head(tickets2)


# A tibble: 6 × 3
#ID    Date.Time.Opened    Date.Time.Closed
#<int>              <dttm>              <dttm>
#1     1 2017-01-19 11:51:00 2017-01-30 14:44:00
#2     2 2016-01-22 12:27:00 2017-01-30 13:36:00
#3     3 2017-01-20 17:07:00 2017-01-27 07:24:00
#4     4 2017-01-20 18:23:00 2017-01-27 07:24:00
#5     5 2017-01-20 08:54:00 2017-01-26 12:09:00
#6     6 2017-01-24 18:54:00 2017-01-26 12:09:00
```

The "timeline" is just one column that has each day of the year, the structure of the timeline:

```
#read in timeline
timeline <- read.csv("timeline.csv",header=TRUE)
timeline <- tbl_df(timeline)
timeline

#change date from factor to date
timeline <- mutate(timeline,tDates = mdy(tDates))
timeline

# A tibble: 10 × 1
#tDates
#<date>
#1  2017-01-20
#2  2017-01-21
#3  2017-01-22
#4  2017-01-23
#5  2017-01-24
#6  2017-01-25
#7  2017-01-26
#8  2017-01-27
#9  2017-01-28
#10 2017-01-29
```

Here is what I would LIKE to get out at the end:

```
##----
##----DESIRED OUTCOME: ------
##----
#tDates ticketsOpen
#1   1/20/17           2
#2   1/21/17           6
#3   1/22/17           6
#4   1/23/17           7
#5   1/24/17           8
#6   1/25/17           9
#7   1/26/17           7
#8   1/27/17           4
#9   1/28/17           2
#10  1/29/17           2

#=======================
```

Here is what I have written after setting up the data:

```
# write a function which takes a date, searches the tickets table and     
returns the number of tickets that are open

nOpenTickets <- function(x){
nrow(filter(tickets,
x > mdy_hm(Date.Time.Opened) &
x < mdy_hm(Date.Time.Closed)))
}


#Add a column to the timeline with the number returned by the function 
(the number of open tickets on that date)

timeline <- mutate(timeline,ticketsOpen = nOpenTickets(tDates))
timeline


# my results: 
## A tibble: 10 × 2
#tDates ticketsOpen
#<date>       <int>
#1  2017-01-20           0
#2  2017-01-21           0
#3  2017-01-22           0
#4  2017-01-23           0
#5  2017-01-24           0
#6  2017-01-25           0
#7  2017-01-26           0
#8  2017-01-27           0
#9  2017-01-28           0
#10 2017-01-29           0
```

Note: if I don't format my tickets, then it all ends up with "7"...I don't know why, either.

Unfortunately, either I get formatting warnings relating to the dates, or it doesn't run at all, but I don't ever get different calculated values for every row.

I am not a professional programmer, so I may easily be missing some things. I have looked at former questions, but they are not quite the same (not R) or perhaps over my head: [dplyr: grouping and summarizing/mutating data with rolling time windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187931/dplyr-grouping-and-summarizing-mutating-data-with-rolling-time-windows)  and [For each row of one table, count entries in another table pointing to each of those rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002043/for-each-row-of-one-table-count-entries-in-another-table-pointing-to-each-of-th)

Below is the dump of the tickets and timeline objects for easy loading. I am thinking there are some issues between mixing tables, dplyr use, and date formatting that are tripping me up. In my head the logic is so clear, but I'm just not coding it right. :-)

I am wondering...should I not use dplyr and lubridate for this?

Thank you for any advice!

Tickets:

```
> dput(tickets)
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Date.Time.Opened = structure(c(1L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("1/19/17 11:51", 
"1/20/17 16:48", "1/20/17 17:07", "1/20/17 18:23", "1/20/17 8:54", 
"1/22/16 12:27", "1/23/17 11:22", "1/24/17 18:54", "1/25/17 11:33", 
"1/9/17 8:57"), class = "factor"), Date.Time.Closed = structure(c(8L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1/25/17 13:46", 
"1/25/17 15:06", "1/25/17 16:31", "1/26/17 12:08", "1/26/17 12:09", 
"1/27/17 7:24", "1/30/17 13:36", "1/30/17 14:44"), class = "factor")),     
.Names = c("ID", 
"Date.Time.Opened", "Date.Time.Closed"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Timeline:

```
> dput(timeline)
structure(list(tDates = structure(c(17186, 17187, 17188, 17189, 
17190, 17191, 17192, 17193, 17194, 17195), class = "Date")), .Names =       
"tDates", class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**=============================================**

**UPDATE**

**=============================================**

Here's what ended up working (Thanks, alistaire!)

```
#packages
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# load in data
tickets <- read.csv("tickets.csv",header=TRUE)
timeline <- read.csv("timeline.csv",header=TRUE)

#change from factor to date
timeline <- mutate(timeline,tDates = mdy(tDates))

# create new df that shows how many are open each day
tickets2 <- 
tickets %>% 
mutate_at(-1, mdy_hm) %>% 
mutate(int = interval(Date.Time.Opened, Date.Time.Closed));     timeline %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(n = sum(tDates %within% tickets2$int))
```

Comment: Here's a tidyverse approach, but it returns slightly different numbers than what you posted: `library(tidyverse); tickets %>% mutate_at(-1, as.Date, '%m/%d/%y') %>% mutate(tDates = map2(Date.Time.Opened, Date.Time.Closed, seq, by = 'day')) %>% unnest(tDates) %>% count(tDates) %>% right_join(timeline)`. I think there's a nice way to do this with data.table, too, if you speak that grammar.

Comment: @alistaire, Thanks, I'll try this out! It's very possible my numbers could be slightly off as I tried to figure out what the numbers would be in Excel for this post. I'll make a comment once I try it out!

Comment: A more direct alternative with `lubridate::\`%within%\``: `tickets2 <- tickets %>% mutate_at(-1, mdy_hm) %>% mutate(int = interval(Date.Time.Opened, Date.Time.Closed)); timeline %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n = sum(tDates %within% tickets2$int))`

Comment: Update: I am getting an error: `Error: Additional arguments should be named` It might be coming from the mutate_at line? (I'm not familiar enough with the mutate_at. I'll try your direct alternative!

Comment: Ah! for some reason the **lubridate::`%within%`:**  was triggering an error: `Error in lubridate.....object 'lubridate' not found`  (Even though I loaded it and ran and it still stated that.) I ran starting at the "tickets2" and i got results! Thank you. ;-)  Now I need to go and step through your code so I can figure out exactly what it is doing! :-)